# Why operations placed on GPU are also executed on CPU (tensorflow)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, profiler

I use tensorflow profiler to profile my model to see how much time is consumed by each operation. I find some strange behavior, for example, `Conv2D` operation which is placed on GPU (I set `log_device_placement=True` to see the placement) also has a large CPU execution time. Here is the code I use to do profiling (tensorflow 1.4.0):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.profiler import option_builder

builder = option_builder.ProfileOptionBuilder
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
# run and collect metadata
my_session.run(fetch_something, feed_dict=feed_dict, 
  options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
profiler_opts = builder(builder.time_and_memory()).order_by('micros').build()
# this will output the following results
tf.profiler.profile(my_graph, run_meta=run_metadata, cmd='scope', options=profiler_opts)
```

Here is the output of profiler:

```
node name | requested bytes | total execution time | accelerator execution time | cpu execution time
MyScope/Conv2D (4511.35MB/4511.35MB, 823.47ms/823.47ms, 445.37ms/445.37ms, 378.11ms/378.11ms)
```

From the profiling result, the `Conv2D` operation (`tf.nn.conv2d`) takes 378.11ms on CPU and 445.37ms on GPU. Why don't tensorflow only use GPU for `Conv2D`? Is the CPU time for data transfer between memory and GPU because this op takes a lot of memory (4511.35MB)?

======== update ========

Another phenomenon I just found. When the "requested bytes" of `Conv2D` is large (in my case >4GB), the CPU execution time is long (about 400~500ms). When the "requested bytes" is small (in my case 1.5GB), the CPU execution time is short (about 15ms). I guess the CPU execution time of `Conv2D` is related with the memory consumption. However I don't why in different batch (`my_session.run`), `Conv2D` uses a different amount of "requested bytes." The tensor on which `Conv2D` is applied has almost the same size across different batches.

Comment: To can help more pls provide [Minimal, Complete(), and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to able to test it for us.

Comment: @Geeocode, Thanks. Reproducing this example is not very easy. Because in my code, I use two layers of `Conv2D`, the first layer is what I have shown in the question. The second layer, which takes the output of the first layer as input, doesn't have this issue. The CPU time of the second `Conv2D` is 2.09ms and its GPU time is 43.04ms. I guess execution time depends on your entire graph structure and memory usage of each operation.

Comment: Reproducing examples always need works of course, but we need it, because 1. we can help more quicker 2. better 3. convenient 4. exacter. It is for you, because you wont get answers that really matter if one who can really could answer the question simply skip it not to want to dive in endless guessings just upon some foggy theories what is going on around.

Comment: An example for community reaction from the same question: [Why Tensorflow Op kernel using both GPU & CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219663/why-tensorflow-op-kernel-using-both-gpu-cpu?rq=1)

Comment: I will try to make a reproducible example. I also updated my question with some new observations.

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't see your whole graph, but I assume that you feed data to the `feed_dict` continuously.
So each time the tensors are evaluated, they take the value of the **next element** in the underlying dataset. This takes time from **CPU** as well.
There is possibility to feed data directly from **GPU** memory if you have enough for holding data in it via `tf.Tensor` object, see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#reading_input_data):

> If all of your input data fit in memory, the simplest way to create a
>   Dataset from them is to convert them to tf.Tensor objects and use
>   Dataset.from_tensor_slices().

An example from the corresponding section of [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#reading_input_data):

```
# Load the training data into two NumPy arrays, for example using `np.load()`.
with np.load("/var/data/training_data.npy") as data:
  features = data["features"]
  labels = data["labels"]

# Assume that each row of `features` corresponds to the same row as `labels`.
assert features.shape[0] == labels.shape[0]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
```

> Note that the above code snippet will embed the features and labels
>   arrays in your TensorFlow graph as tf.constant() operations. This
>   works well for a small dataset, but wastes memory---because the
>   contents of the array will be copied multiple times---and can run into
>   the 2GB limit for the tf.GraphDef protocol buffer.

But this is not the case. So based of the information you provided, I think the CPU consumption is mainly due (or fully) to the **data feeding operation** to to the this graph's next input.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! It is very informative. However, the input of my `Conv2D` is not the data fed to my graph. Actually, my `Conv2D` takes an intermediate tensor as input. So I guess it is not the feed_dict that slows my model down. BTW, I am using tf.data and prefetch. Maybe `Conv2D` is fetching the input (the intermediate tensor in my case) from memory?

Comment: @jzb I think tensorflow watch what is the CPU and GPU usage during the Conv2D ops and although it works from **buffer** via `prefetch()`, this buffer will run out after a while, thus it has to be reloaded again during the measured period. Note that you should play with `prefetch()` `buffer` parameter to optimize this part of process... By the way feed_dict actually doesn't slows down your model as you mentioned, as you can see that CPU time consumption is **less** then GPU time, so CPU works fine under the GPU's hands.

Comment: @jzb If you find my answer acceptable or/and informative please accept it or/and upvote it. Thank you.

Comment: I though the CPU and GPU execution time are not in parallel because the total execution time is the sum. And my `Conv2D` is applied to an internal tensor (not the input data of the graph) so it has little to do with the `feed_dict ` or `prefetch`.

Comment: The two resources i.e. CPU and GPU definitely do work parallel for maximizing the efficiency, this is not a question and as I wrote above doesn't matter that the input data directly or indirectly but feeds the Conv2D in the form: input data -> input tensor -> prefetch() buffer -> Conv2D tensor. Thus if Conv2D needs data it pulls the whole line together if the buffer of prefetch() run out. Anyway I will test this with my own config and I will write my experiences in my answer as an update.